# Show that $\sum\limits_{1\leq m^2+n^2 \leq R^2} \frac{1}{m^2+n^2} = 2\pi \log R +O(1)$ as $R\to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

This is an exercise in E.M.Stein's textbook: Complex Analysis P279-3. About proving the series $\sum_{n+m\tau \in \Lambda^{*}} \frac{1}{\vert n+m\tau \vert ^2}$ does not converge, where $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$ and lattices $\Lambda^{*}=\Lambda-(0,0)$. The idea is that we have known $\vert m\vert +\vert n\vert \approx \vert n+m\tau \vert.$ It suffices to show that

$$\sum_{1\leq m^2+n^2 \leq R^2} \frac{1}{m^2+n^2} = 2\pi \log R +O(1)$$ as $R\to \infty$. How to show the above identity?

Comment: See Theorem B.1 (with $d=2$) of https://ctnt-summer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1632/2016/02/CTNTmodularforms.pdf.

Comment: @KCd Thanks! It is more general than stein's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

You can consider $a_{n} = \# \{(p,q)\| \ p^2 + q^2 = n\}$ and use 
$a_1 + \ldots + a_n \simeq \pi n $ to get  an estimate for 
$\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$ using the [Abel transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts).

If you only want the divergence of the series and not precise estimates, you can 
use $m^2 + n^2 \simeq (|m|+|n|)^2$ and  $b_n= \#\{(p,q) | \ |p|+|q|=n\}= 4(n+1)$. In higher dimensions $d$, $b_n$ grows like $n^{d-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can compare the sum with this integral

$$
\iint_{ 1 \leq x^2 + y^2  \leq R^2 } \frac{dx dy}{x^2 + y^2} = \int_1^R \int_0^{2\pi} r \frac{dr}{r^2} = 2\pi \log R, 
$$
where we used polar coordinates ( integration over spheres in higher dimensions) to compute the integral.

Comment: Thanks. But how about the details about the relation between the series and integral?

Comment: imagine you split the circle of radius R into squares of size 1 (not all will fit, but the difference is controllable). Then on a square with bottom-left and upper-right vertices $(m,n)$ , $(m+1, n+1)$  (assume $m, n \geq 1$) you can estimate the integral of $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$ by $\frac{1}{m^2 + n^2} $ from above and by $\frac{1}{(m+1)^2 + (n+1)^2}$ from below ( these are 2 extremes of the function). Then apply summation (following the necessary details) and you'll get the idea.